# jQuery Cycle Plugin in combination with CSSPIE results in empty slides in IE8 and below

Tags: jquery, cycle, css3pie

I have an image slideshow that uses the jQuery Cycle Plugin. The images have rounded corners so I use CSS3PIE behavior to support this in IE8 and below. But with PIE only the first image is displayed while the other images just give me a empty slide (in IE8 and below). When I disable PIE, everything looks fine.

Any idea's?

The Javascript:

```
$('#content-header-right-slideshow').cycle({
fx:         'fade',
speed:      1500,
timeout:    4000
});
```

The HTML

```
<div id="content-header-right-slideshow">
<img src="/images/content-header-right-img01.jpg" width="283" height="249" title="" alt="" />
<img src="/images/content-header-right-img02.jpg" width="283" height="249" title="" alt="" />
<img src="/images/content-header-right-img03.jpg" width="283" height="249" title="" alt="" />
<img src="/images/content-header-right-img04.jpg" width="283" height="249" title="" alt="" />
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
#content #content-header-right-slideshow {width:283px; height:249px; }
#content #content-header-right-slideshow img {-webkit-border-radius: 16px 0 16px 0; -moz-border-radius:  16px 0 16px 0; border-radius:  16px 0 16px 0; behavior: url(/css/PIE.htc); width:283px; height:249px; }
```

Comment: I looks like it has to do with the fade effect. When I apply other effects to the plugin it looks good....